# I want to uninstall Playstore

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation

I need to uninstall the Playstore on my Android device due to internal memory issues. All my updates are done externally. I want to inquire if it is safe to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe.
But u should be rooted to remove it.

I have removed play-store on my Galaxy Fit a long time ago, reason being it always triggered the installation of Google play Services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My phone is rooted so I guess it will work.